# How to specify multiple input arguments stored in a file to a command?

Tags: bash, arguments

I would like to convert several webpages into a pdf file, by:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/about-this-site.html http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/about-this-site/who-this-site-is-for.html all.pdf
```

If I put the two input arguments into a text file called "links":

```
http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/about-this-site.html 
http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/about-this-site/who-this-site-is-for.html
```

how shall I specify the input arguments in terms of the file? The following doesn't work:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf "$(cat links)" all.pdf
Loading pages (1/6)
Counting pages (2/6)
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError
```

Answer (score 4):

When you used double quotes in `"$(cat links)"`, the shell treated the whole content of file as one string, not separated fields (with each field is one line in file).

You can do something like this:

```
set -f  # Turn off globbing
IFS='   # Split on newline only
'
wkhtmltopdf $(cat links) all.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks. Why "Turn off globbing"?

Comment: Not download all the webpages, when I include all the links on the right column in http://think-like-a-git.net/ in the `links` file.

Comment: @Tim: An url string can contain `[`, `]`, `*` or `?`, which are shell metacharacters to perform globbing.

Comment: I put the links in a text file like this http://paste.ubuntu.com/14045177/. the command only convert the first or two webpages, and not the other webpages.

Comment: @Tim: I'm not familiar with `wkhtmltopdf`, maybe you should run with some links first to make sure it works, `wkhtmltopdf link1 link2 link3 link4 all.pdf`.

Comment: it doesn't really matter, anyway. but it can be easier for people to learn the order of the input parsing process if the ideas aren't mixed up, i think.

Answer (score 2):

You could:

```
readarray -t a < file
wkhtmltopdf "${a[@]}" all.pdf
```

---

- `readarray` reads the `file` into an array line by line, `-t` removes the trailing newline.
- `"${a[@]}"` refers to all array elements. This generates a command in the form:

```bsh
wkhtmltopdf "${a[0]}" "${a[1]}" "${a[2]}" "..." all.pdf
```